# Sending parameters to same url from dropdown menu

Tags: bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I'm trying have multiple menu links hit the same  razor page, but send different parameters to return different results from the database.

Normally I would just append the value to a querystring and retrieve it when the new page link is clicked, but I don't know how razor pages do this.
For example, I want to go to my razor page called, CourseList.cshtml, and pass, Accounting, as the value so I can only pull back accounting courses.

```
asp-page="/CourseList?ccat=accounting"
```

I know I could make separate CourseList pages for each course category, but that sounds dirty and will have higher maintenance as new categories are added.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark dropdown-toggle" 
href="#" id="navbaddrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Courses
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/CourseList?ccat=accounting">Accounting</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/CourseList?ccat=general">General</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/CourseList?ccat=it">IT</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/CourseList?ccat=manufacturing">Manufacturing</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value to appear in a query string, pass it to the `asp-route-*` parameter of the anchor tag helper:

`<a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/CourseList" asp-route-ccat="accounting">Accounting</a>`

The `*` is replaced with the name of the parameter.

Alternatively, you can pass it as a route parameter (a segment in the URL) by specifying a route data parameter in the Razor page as part of the `@page` directive:

```
@page "{ccat}"
```

Then the generated links will look like this:

```
CourseList/accounting
CourseList/general
```

In the page itself, you add a property representing the parameter with the `BindProperty` attribute applied to it:

```
public class CourseListModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
    public string Ccat { get; set; }

    ...
```

Model binding will automatically assign the query string value to the public property.
More information:

- [Model Binding](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding)
- [Anchor Tag Helper](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper)
- [Routing in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much. I've been doing classic asp and asp.net for so long that I'm struggling to bend my brain around this new stuff. This was very helpful.